# Android Emulator crashes on startup with Crash reason: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ Crash address: 0xab

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, intel

Using:

- Android Arctic Fox 2020.3.1
- Android 11.0
- Android SDK Build-Tools 31.0.0
- Android Emulator 30.7.5
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 31.0.3
- Intel I7-4700HQ processor

Any emulator I try to launch will crash on launch with:

```
Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ Crash address: 0xab
```

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

- Using different emulators
- Using software rendering
- Cold boot
- Wiping data

How do I get any emulator to launch?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on macOS 11.5.1.

It has been solved by updating Android SDK Build-Tools, Android SDK Command-line Tools, Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-Tools as shown in the following picture:

[image: Android Studio Settings - Android SDK]